# Open file in a running nvim-qt instance

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to open new files from the command line on Windows in a single nvim-qt instance that is already open.

I know the existence of the `--server` option, but how do I know the IP or the socket name or path of the running instance?

Comment: Sorry now i see, nvim has removed the `--servername` attribute.
you can get the server socket with `:echo v:servername` more about that here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5348/how-can-i-use-servername-and-remote-in-neovim. There also seems to be a plugin: https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote.

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I failed to find. Thank you!

Comment: Ok so after my initial excitement, I can't still open a file in an existing instance. So far I'm able to open a new nvim-qt window with `nvim-qt.exe --server "127.0.0.1:7777"` or any other address that is in use (`:echo serverlist()`). If I add a file to edit to the command though, it no longer opens up a window or anything.

Comment: it woukd be `--remote` not `--server` but this both seems to be removed (i do not use neovim, but vim itself) there is an API for the usecase you have, but calling it seems non trivial. I would go for the plugin if possible, and if not try to comment under carpetsmoker's post. Maybe he knows more. Unfortunaly i can't help you any further without neovim and without windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [el_technic0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233010/el-technic0) said, the [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) utility is the easiest way to get remote file opening to work. I even added an `alias` to it in my `.bashrc` file (alongside the listen address definition) for easier invocation:

```
export NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/nvimsocket
alias vim='nvr --remote'
```

This way the first call will start a new neovim instance, and subsequent calls will be forwarded to that instance.

You may also want to add the `set hidden` option to your `init.vim` configuration file, otherwise subsequent calls may fail if the current buffer contains unsaved changes.

Comment: Ok, but the question states "I want to open new files from the command line *on Windows*" and this thing doesn't work on WIndows.

Comment: Apparently it worked well enough for the question owner though, since he accepted my answer.